# PySpark: Explode schema columns does not match with underlying nested schema

Tags: pyspark, explode, azure-synapse

I am using pyspark in combination with Azure-Synapse. I am reading multiple nested JSON with the same structure in a dataframe using the below sample:

```
{
    "AmountOfOrders": 2,
    "TotalEarnings": 1800,
    "OrderDetails": [
        {
            "OrderNumber": 1,
            "OrderDate": "2022-7-06",
            "OrderLine": [
                {
                    "LineNumber": 1,
                    "Product": "Laptop",
                    "Price": 1000
                },
                {
                    "LineNumber": 2,
                    "Product": "Tablet",
                    "Price": 500
                },
                {
                    "LineNumber": 3,
                    "Product": "Mobilephone",
                    "Price": 300
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "OrderNumber": 2,
            "OrderDate": "2022-7-06",
            "OrderLine": [
                {
                    "LineNumber": 1,
                    "Product": "Printer",
                    "Price": 100,
                    "Discount": 0
                },
                {
                    "LineNumber": 2,
                    "Product": "Paper",
                    "Price": 50,
                    "Discount": 0
                },
                {
                    "LineNumber": 3,
                    "Product": "Toner",
                    "Price": 30,
                    "Discount": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to get the the LineNumbers of Ordernumber 1 in a separate dataframe using a generic function which extract the array and Struct of the dataframe. Using the code below:

```
def read_nested_structure(df,excludeList,messageType,coll):
    display(df.limit(10))
    print('read_nested_structure')
    cols =[]
    match = 0
    match_field = ""
    print(df.schema[coll].dataType.fields)
    for field in df.schema[coll].dataType.fields:

        for c in excludeList:
            if c == field.name:
                print('Match = ' + field.name)
                match = 1
        if match == 0:   
            # cols.append(coll)
            cols.append(col(coll + "." + field.name).alias(field.name))
        match = 0 
        #         cols.append(coll)
    print(cols)  
    df = df.select(cols)
    return df

def read_nested_structure_2(df,excludeList,messageType):
    cols =[]
    match = 0
    for coll in df.schema.names:
        if isinstance(df.schema[coll].dataType, ArrayType):
            print(  coll +  "-- : Array")
            df = df.withColumn(coll, explode(coll).alias(coll))
            cols.append(coll)

        elif isinstance(df.schema[coll].dataType, StructType):
            if messageType == 'Header':
                for field in df.schema[coll].dataType.fields:
                    cols.append(col(coll + "." + field.name).alias(coll + "_" + field.name))
            
            elif messageType == 'Content':
                print('Struct - Content')
                for field in df.schema[coll].dataType.fields:
                    cols.append(col(coll + "." + field.name).alias(field.name))

        else:
            for c in excludeList:
                if c == coll:
                    match = 1
            if match == 0:
                cols.append(coll)
                        
    df = df.select(cols)
    return df

df = spark.read.load(datalakelocation + '/test.json', format='json')
df =  unpack_to_content_dataframe_simple_2(df,exclude)
df = df.filter(df.OrderNumber == 1)
df =  unpack_to_content_dataframe_simple_2(df,exclude)
display(df.limit(10))
```

which result in the following dataframe:

[image]

as you can see the yellow marked attribute is added to the dataframe which is not part of OrderNumber 1. How can I filter a row in the dataframe which results in a update schema ( in this case without the Discount attribute)?

Comment: What does `unpack_to_content_dataframe_simple_2(df,exclude)` do? And can you please clarify about what you mean by `How can I filter a row in the dataframe which results in a update schema?`

Comment: The function extract the nested array or struct  with the explode function. And put it in a new dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I have used `read_nested_structure_2()` function in the following way to get the same results as yours. The code I used to get this result using `read_nested_structure_2()` is as follows:

```
x = read_nested_structure_2(df,[],'Header')
y = read_nested_structure_2(x,[],'Content')

y = y.filter(y.OrderNumber == 1)

z = read_nested_structure_2(y,[],'Header')
final = read_nested_structure_2(z,[],'Content')

display(final)
```

The output of after using this code is:

[image]

- The column `Discount` will be created even if it is specified for one `Product` in the entire input JSON. In order to remove this column, we have to do it separately to get another dataframe without `Discount` (only if it is invalid).
- You are going to use the same function to extract data from **StructType** or **ArrayType**, it is not recommended to write code to remove fields (say `Discount`) having all null values, in the same function. Doing so would complicate the code.
- Instead, we can write another function which does this work for us. This function should remove a column where all of its values are `null`. The following is the function that can be used to do this.

```
def exclude_fields_that_dont_exist(filtered_df):
    cols=[]

    #iterate through columns
    for column in filtered_df.columns:
        
        #null_count is the count of null values in a column
        null_count = filtered_df.filter(filtered_df[column].isNull()).count() 

        #check if null_count equals the total column value count
        #if they are equal, those columns are not required (Like Discount)
        if(filtered_df.select(column).count() != null_count):
            cols.append(column)

    #return dataframe with required columns
    return filtered_df.select(*cols)
```

- When you use this function on the **filtered dataframe** (`final` in my case), then you get a resulting dataframe as shown below:

```
mydf = exclude_fields_that_dont_exist(final) 
# removes columns from a dataframe that have all null values.

display(mydf)
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

- For example, for `OrderNumber=1`, the product `Laptop` has a 10% discount and the rest of the products (for the same order number) don't have a discount value (in the JSON).
- The function needs to include the `Discount` column since it is a required information.
- To avoid using more loops inside a function, you can also consider replacing all the null values with `0` since a `Product` with no `Discount` specified (**null** value) is same as a Product with `Discount` value as `0` (If this is feasible, then you can use `fill() or fillna()` functions **to fill null values with any desired value**)